# How can I disable an NGUI button when I pause my game?

Tags: unity, ngui

There is an NGUI button in my game, which when pressed increases the player's power.

When I press the escape key, my game pauses completely. But the button still functions normally. Here's how I check for pausing:

```
void Update () 
{       
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))     
    {
        if(isPaused && Time.timeScale == 1.0f){
            Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
            AudioListener.volume = 1;
        }       
        else
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1.0f;  
            AudioListener.volume = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like the button to be deactivated when the game is paused. It should be visible, but not be clickable or anything. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "disable?" Do you want to change the button's appearance? Or just make clicking it do nothing? What have you tried? Can you not just query whether your game is paused in the click handler and early out? Et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `isEnabled` of the desired `UIButton` to false. This will just disable it's collider, and it will still be visible. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine the simplest way would be to give the Script that accesses the button knowledge about `isPaused`. Some type of static access would make sense to me in this case, since multiple scripts might need to change their behaviour based on the value of `isPaused`.

```
public class ButtonBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

....

public void onPress() {
    if (!PauserClass.isPaused) {
        makePlayerStronger(); 
    }
}

....

}
```